# How to define a Date for run-time parameters in SQL

Tags: mysql, database, date

I need to filter query results that are between a Start and End date and I'm doing so with Run-Time parameters.

```
AND (cr.COMPLETED_DATE BETWEEN (:StartDate) AND (:EndDate));
```

My problem is I keep getting an invalid identifier error (because the input is expected to be a date) and I don't know what format the Date needs to be in to work.

```
Error validating FROM clause: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
```

I realize that I need to input a DATE but I don't know the structure (20150529, 29-MAY-2015, 05/29/2015, etc.)

Comment: What is the format of `cr.COMPLETED_DATE`? That should be the format of your parameters.

Comment: But there are many date formats. '2015-05-01', '5/01/2015', '20150501' are just a few examples. Date formats depend on how the column of your table is set up.

Comment: @SQLHound: **NO**. format of a `DATE` column is *not* dependent "on how your table is setup". The Oracle `DATE` datatype is an internal format. The datatype conversion from/to string representation is dependent on the format model, in the TO_DATE and TO_CHAR functions. Oracle uses a default format model when one is not supplied, and the default is the value from `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` initialization parameter.

Comment: At the time of the answer, the column of the OP was undefined. I don't know about you, but in my experience, the column could have been set up with many options besides `DATE`, and to avoid casting the parameter, I thought it was better than to assume. Standards are only as good as when they are actually followed.

Comment: @SQLHound: your recommendation to look at the table definition to determine the datatype is spot on. The question doesn't show that, and it doesn't show the whole query. But if the section of the statement is whatthe ORA-932

Comment: @SQLHound: We concluded that the column was DATE datatype, based on an assumption that the portion of statement shown in the question is whats causing the ORA-932 error. (It looks like OP has done a good job of narrowing it down to this). The error indicates that Oracle is performing an implicit TO_DATE datatype conversion, which it would be doing *only* if the COMPLETED_DATE column was defined as `DATE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message, `COMPLETED_DATE` appears to be defined as `DATE`.

The "format" of the `DATE` values is **not** dependent on the column definition.

The setting of the the **`NLS_DATE_FORMAT`** parameter is what determines the default format model to be used by the `TO_DATE` and `TO_CHAR` functions. (You can retrieve the current setting of that parameter with a query of `v$nls_parameter` view.)

The session inherits a default value when it starts, but the setting within the session can be changed with an `ALTER SESSION` statement.

---

I recommend that you **don't** write your code to be *dependent* on a particular setting of NLS_DATE_FORMAT.

---

The error message indicates that there's an implicit datatype conversion going on. In order to do a comparison, Oracle needs the values on either side to be of compatible types. Your query is comparing two different datatypes: `DATE` and `VARCHAR2` (string)

With this:

```
  date BETWEEN varchar2 AND varchar2
```

Oracle is doing this:

```
  date BETWEEN TO_DATE(varchar2) AND TO_DATE(varchar2)
```

And when you don't supply a format model for the TO_DATE function, Oracle uses the setting of `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`.

You could write your query with an *explicit* call the `TO_DATE` function with a second argument that supplies a format model. You can use whatever format model, to match whatever the format of the string you are passing in.

```
  date BETWEEN TO_DATE(string,format) AND TO_DATE(string,format)
```

For example, if the strings you are passing are in the format like '2015-05-29'

```
 cr.completed_date BETWEEN TO_DATE( :StartDate ,'YYYY-MM-DD')
                       AND TO_DATE( :EndDate   ,'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

---

**N.B.** The Oracle DATE datatype contains both date and time. With a `BETWEEN` comparison like above, you're only going to get `completed_date` values at the very first second of EndDate, any value of `completed_date` that sometime later, during EndDate will not be returend.)

Comment: Reference: [**Format Models** http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210)

Answer (score 0):

In order to find out the setup of `COMPLETED_DATE`, you'll need to query the table setup.

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM mytable
```

should give you the entire table and the format of each column in the `Type` column.

Another approach could be looking at a few entries of the table

```
SELECT TOP 10 
 cr.COMPLETED_DATE
FROM mytable cr
```